# Solar flares/CME dangers to life?

Tags: earth, solar-flare, coronal-mass-ejection

I know a repeat of the [1859 Carrington Event](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2014/02may_superstorm/) (coronal mass ejection) would pose a severe risk to power grids and telecommunication networks but wouldn't pose an immediate threat to life.

If a large solar flare can release [10e32 ergs](https://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/sftheory/flare.htm#:%7E:text=Large%20flares%20can%20emit%20up%20to%2010%2032,are%20typically%20three%20stages%20to%20a%20solar%20flare.) of energy, is there an energy level where a solar flare or CME would pose an immediate threat to any life on the Earth that doesn't live below sea level.

Comment: The power grid being affected *is* an immediate threat to lives.

Comment: @StephenG I didn't specify human life in my question. I believe the failure of the power grid would not be an immediate threat to much of the animal kingdom.

Comment: Possibly useful:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258093/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/568946/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/202229/59023

Answer (score 1):

Abrevaya et al. (2020) in "The UV surface habitability of Proxima b: first experiments revealing probable life survival to stellar flares" ([abstract](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020MNRAS.494L..69A/abstract), [PDF](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/2020MNRAS.494L..69A/EPRINT_PDF)) say:

"Our results show the impact that a typical flare and a superflare would have on life: when microorganisms receive very high fluences of UVC, such as those expected to reach the surface of Proxima b after a typical flare or a superflare, a fraction of the population is able to survive. Our study suggests that life could cope with highly UV irradiated environments in exoplanets under conditions that cannot be found on Earth. "

That suggests that total-extinction conditions aren't found on Earth, either.  The paper has a lot more detail of their assumptions and modeling, but that's my quick takeaway from the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that with our current atmosphere and magnetic field there's not a "direct" threat to life as they shield the Earth.

The atmosphere is [opaque to X-ray radiation](http://gsp.humboldt.edu/OLM/Courses/GSP_216_Online/lesson2-1/atmosphere.html) that can come from outside. It seems that much of that opacity comes from water vapor, and [the amount of that in the atmosphere changes](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/global-maps/MYDAL2_M_SKY_WV) depending on different factors. X-ray radiation has also effects on the ionosphere and can change its size, which affects communications but I don't know whether life is affected for that.

Earth's magnetic field is disturbed by a CME and that has also various effects like inducing currents that, as you said, pose a risk to power grids and telecommunications. However there's another effect that's also associated with CMEs and solar flares: [Solar Energetic Particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_energetic_particles), these types of events are, I believe, the one that could have a more direct effect to life. If they are happening together with the disturbance of the magnetic field produced by a CME, then our shield is weakened. The maximum flux of the chain reaction they produced when they reach Earth happens at 18km above the sea level, and at the altitude of a commercial flight is ~300 times more than at sea level. However, only seems to pose a "risk" to frequent flyers (crew and passengers) as the cumulative effects could produce cancer. I've extracted these numbers from the [Extreme Space Weather report by the Royal Academic of Engineering](https://www.raeng.org.uk/publications/reports/space-weather-full-report) and references therein.